# Ruby: Sorting an array of strings, in alphabetical order, that includes some arrays of strings

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, sorting, enumeration

Say I have:

`a = ["apple", "pear", ["grapes", "berries"], "peach"]`

and I want to sort by:

```
a.sort_by do |f|
  f.class == Array ? f.to_s : f
end
```

I get:

```
[["grapes", "berries"], "apple", "peach", "pear"]
```

Where I actually want the items in alphabetical order, with array items being sorted on their first element:

```
["apple", ["grapes", "berries"], "peach", "pear"]
```

or, preferably, I want:

```
["apple", "grapes, berries", "peach", "pear"]
```

If the example isn't clear enough, I'm looking to sort the items in alphabetical order.

Any suggestions on how to get there?

I've tried a few things so far yet can't seem to get it there. Thanks.

Comment: what is the sorting logic, you want to have? explain it please

Comment: why `["grapes", "berries"]` does come after `Apple` ?

Comment: I'd like to sort in alphabetical order, with the first item of a string array being used in comparison to the other strings

Comment: Can whoever take back their down and close vote, please? I've clarified the question. Let me know if there is any other part that's confusing.

Comment: Why grapes berries and not berries grapes? Descending order in the inner array?

Comment: You should edit `I'd like to sort in alphabetical order, with the first item of a string array being used in comparison to the other strings` into your question.  One has to read the comments to understand your desired sorting scheme.

Comment: @roippi Good suggestion. I'll make the edit. Thanks.

Comment: Please before asking, decide first what you want to get from here. When people answering and finished, don't change the post.. Please.. remember in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
a.sort_by { |f| f.class == Array ? f.first : f }
```

Comment: add `.flatten` and you'd get him his preferred output. Regardless, +1 :-)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, you are right with the edited question. Anyway is the OP just wants keep this kind of order I would not flatten the array because it could be confusing and also it is costly as well.

Comment: @Abdo, preferred format has `"grapes, berries"`, not `"grapes", "berries"`, which `flatten` gives.

Answer (score 3):

I would do

```
a = ["apple", "pear", ["grapes", "berries"], "peach"]
a.map { |e| Array(e).join(", ") }.sort
# => ["apple", "grapes, berries", "peach", "pear"]
```

Comment: I like the first one, Arup.  You could have `[e]` instead of `Array(e)` (though I don't have a preference).  `join(', ')` gives a more pleasing spacing.  Did you notice that the results of your second solution gives results in a slightly incorrect format?  If so, join the party, as at least two others, including me, made the same mistake.

Answer (score 2):

[Array#sort_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21) clearly is the right method, but here's a reminder of how [Array#sort](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) would be used here:

```
  a.sort do |s1,s2| 
    t1 = (s1.is_a? Array) ? s1.first : s1
    t2 = (s2.is_a? Array) ? s2.first : s2
    t1 <=> t2
  end.map {|e| (e.is_a? Array) ? e.join(', ') : e }
    #=> ["apple", "grapes, berries", "peach", "pear"]
```

@theTinMan pointed out that `sort` is quite a bit slower than `sort_by` here, and gave a reference that explains why.  I've been meaning to see how the [Benchmark module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) is used, so took the opportunity to compare the two methods for the problem at hand.  I used @Rafa's solution for `sort_by` and mine for `sort`.

For testing, I constructed an array of 100 random samples (each with 10,000 random elements to be sorted) in advance, so the benchmarks would not include the time needed to construct the samples (which was not insignificant).  8,000 of the 10,000 elements were random strings of 8 lowercase letters.  The other 2,000 elements were 2-tuples of the form `[str1, str2]`, where `str1` and `str2` were each random strings of 8 lowercase letters.  I benchmarked with other parameters, but the bottom-line results did not vary significantly.

```
require 'benchmark'

# n: total number of items to sort
# m: number of two-tuples [str1, str2] among n items to sort
# n-m: number of strings among n items to sort
# k: length of each string in samples
# s: number of sorts to perform when benchmarking

def make_samples(n, m, k, s)
  s.times.with_object([]) { |_, a| a << test_array(n,m,k) }
end

def test_array(n,m,k)
  a = ('a'..'z').to_a 
  r = []
  (n-m).times { r << a.sample(k).join }
  m.times { r << [a.sample(k).join, a.sample(k).join] }
  r.shuffle!
end

# Here's what the samples look like:    
make_samples(6,2,4,4)
  #=> [["bloj", "izlh", "tebz", ["lfzx", "rxko"], ["ljnv", "tpze"], "ryel"],
  #    ["jyoh", "ixmt", "opnv", "qdtk", ["jsve", "itjw"], ["pnog", "fkdr"]],
  #    ["sxme", ["emqo", "cawq"], "kbsl", "xgwk", "kanj", ["cylb", "kgpx"]],
  #    [["rdah", "ohgq"], "bnup", ["ytlr", "czmo"], "yxqa", "yrmh", "mzin"]]

n = 10000 # total number of items to sort
m = 2000  # number of two-tuples [str1, str2] (n-m strings)
k = 8     # length of each string
s = 100   # number of sorts to perform

samples = make_samples(n,m,k,s)

Benchmark.bm('sort_by'.size) do |bm|
  bm.report 'sort_by' do
    samples.each do |s|
      s.sort_by { |f| f.class == Array ? f.first : f }
    end
  end

  bm.report 'sort' do
    samples.each do |s| 
      s.sort do |s1,s2| 
        t1 = (s1.is_a? Array) ? s1.first : s1
        t2 = (s2.is_a? Array) ? s2.first : s2
        t1 <=> t2
      end
    end
  end
end

              user     system      total        real
sort_by   1.360000   0.000000   1.360000 (  1.364781)
sort      4.050000   0.010000   4.060000 (  4.057673)
```

Though it was never in doubt, @theTinMan was right!  I did a few other runs with different parameters, but `sort_by` consistently thumped `sort` by similar performance ratios.

Note the "system" time is zero for `sort_by`.  In other runs it was sometimes zero for `sort`.  The values were always zero or `0.010000`, leading me to wonder what's going on there. (I ran these on a Mac.)

For readers unfamiliar with `Benchmark`, [Benchmark#bm](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html#method-c-bm) takes an argument that equals the amount of left-padding desired for the header row (`user    system...`).  `bm.report` takes a row label as an argument.

Comment: Thanks, @Jessie. I tacked on `flatten` to put the results in the 'preferred' format, but that was based on a misreading of the question.  Later I twigged (see my comment on Matt's answer), but forgot to fix my answer.  It should be OK now.

Comment: While `sort` *can* be used, it's going to be much slower than `sort_by` by its nature. For more information read about ["Schwartzian transform"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Answer (score 1):

You are really close.  Just switch `.to_s` to `.first`.

```
irb(main):005:0> b = ["grapes", "berries"]
=> ["grapes", "berries"]
irb(main):006:0> b.to_s
=> "[\"grapes\", \"berries\"]"
irb(main):007:0> b.first
=> "grapes"
```

Here is one that works:

```
a.sort_by do |f|
  f.class == Array ? f.first : f
end
```

Yields:

```
["apple", ["grapes", "berries"], "peach", "pear"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a.map { |b| b.is_a?(Array) ? b.join(', ') : b }.sort

# => ["apple", "grapes, berries", "peach", "pear"]
```

Comment: Nice one, Matt.  If it were "grape, berry", and "grapefruit" were also in the list, the comma after "grape" would ensure that it is ordered properly ("grape, berry" before "grapefruit").

Answer (score 1):

Replace `to_s` with `join`.

```
a.sort_by do |f|
  f.class == Array ? f.join : f
end

# => ["apple", ["grapes", "berries"], "peach", "pear"]
```

Or more concisely:

```
a.sort_by {|x| [*x].join }

# => ["apple", ["grapes", "berries"], "peach", "pear"]
```

The problem with `to_s` is that it converts your Array to a string that starts with `"["`:

```
"[\"grapes\", \"berries\"]"
```

which comes alphabetically before the rest of your strings.

`join` actually creates the string that you had expected to sort by:

```
"grapesberries"
```

which is alphabetized correctly, according to your logic.

If you don't want the arrays to remain arrays, then it's a slightly different operation, but you will still use `join`.

```
a.map {|x| [*x].join(", ") }.sort

# => ["apple", "grapes, berries", "peach", "pear"]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Sort a Flattened Array

If you just want all elements of your nested array flattened and then sorted in alphabetical order, all you need to do is [flatten](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) and [sort](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-sort). For example:

```
["apple", "pear", ["grapes", "berries"], "peach"].flatten.sort
#=> ["apple", "berries", "grapes", "peach", "pear"]
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants.

Comment: I know it seems reasonable to want this implementation, but this is for a table row's category type, which can have multiple types in some instances. So I have to keep the multiples together. Thanks.